# How to fixed CMFCPropertyListCtrl's column width?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, resize

I have customized the column width `CMFCPropertyListCtrl` by overriding the same class.
**Code:**

```
class CMyPropertyGridCtrl : public CMFCPropertyGridCtrl
{
public:
    void SetFirstColumnWidth(int width)
    {
        m_nLeftColumnWidth = width;
        AdjustLayout();
    }
};
```

And in `OnSize()` method of the class where `pChannelListCtrl` is declare as data member, I have called this method.
I want to fixed second column with size `50`.
**Code:**

```
int iWidth = pChannelListCtrl.GetLeftColumnWidth();
pChannelListCtrl.SetFirstColumnWidth(iWidth + (iWidth - 50));
```

Here, its display as expected.(Second column with size 50).
**Problem:**
I want to keep the second column size fixed. But, here its resizable.

Can you please guide me, how to restrict the column resize.

Thanks,
Abdula

Comment: I have already refereed this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453244/how-to-set-a-cmfcpropertylistctrls-column-width

Answer (score 0):

Override `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::SetLeftColumnWidth`.

The header control for the grid is accessed with `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::GetHeaderCtrl()`

Optionally, you can disable the header control to prevent resizing `GetHeaderCtrl().EnableWindow(FALSE);`

```
class CMyPropertyGridCtrl : public CMFCPropertyGridCtrl
{
public:
    CMyPropertyGridCtrl()
    {
        m_nLeftColumnWidth = 50;
    }

    void make_fixed_header()
    {
        HDITEM hdItem = { 0 };
        hdItem.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
        GetHeaderCtrl().GetItem(0, &hdItem);
        hdItem.fmt |= HDF_FIXEDWIDTH;
        GetHeaderCtrl().SetItem(0, &hdItem);
    }

    void SetLeftColumnWidth(int cx)
    {
        m_nLeftColumnWidth = cx;
        AdjustLayout();
    }

    void OnSize(UINT f, int cx, int cy)
    {
        EndEditItem();
        if (cx > 50)
            m_nLeftColumnWidth = cx - 50; //<- 2nd column will be 50 pixels
        AdjustLayout();
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyPropertyGridCtrl, CMFCPropertyGridCtrl)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Use `HDF_FIXEDWIDTH` to fix the column for header control. From parent window call these functions after the control is created:

```
grid.SetLeftColumnWidth(50);
grid.make_fixed_header();
```

`CMyPropertyGridCtrl::SetLeftColumnWidth` will not detect when column is resized by the user. Override `CMyPropertyGridCtrl::OnHeaderItemChanged` in order to detect changes requested by user.

Comment: `GetHeaderCtrl().EnableWindow(FALSE);` can not prevent resizing. And I want to fixed size of **Second Column** and not First column.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. See edit. Add `ON_WM_SIZE` message, override `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnSize` as shown, to change the column when the whole control is resized.

Comment: There is no issue when whole control is resize. Second column width remain same, as I am calling `SetFirstColumnWidth()`. I want to hide/disable the splitter that change the width of the first and second column.

Comment: If I override `OnSize` method of `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`, the second column is disappear. Even I tried out with different width.

Comment: You are changing the question. See the third edit. `make_fixed_header` will stop the header from resizing if that's what you want. `OnSize` should behave as expected unless width is less than 50, or unless other changes are made.

Comment: I am not changing the question, just providing more info so u get it the actual problem statement. I have tried out your latest edit section, but no luck. Still column are resizable. I want to fixed the size even user change the size of Dockpane.